# C# While Loop (adding the user input to reach a target)

Tags: c#, while-loop

I need to create a program that adding the user input to reach a target, as a result, is just like below.

[image]

I have to use 'While Loop' for this,
but it is difficult for me to use while loop...

Here is my code

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Target Value: 6");

int total = 0;
int target = 6;
int i;
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter #{0}:\t", i);
    total += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

while (total == target);

Console.WriteLine("It took {0} inputs to take the sum to\t{1}",i, total);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Could you please help me to find the problems?

Comment: Mate I can tell you the correct code, but first I would recommend you to read about loops/programming more to build logic

Comment: You can easily replace you `for` loop with a `while` loop.  You should read further on how to use a `while` loop.

Comment: You have a `for` loop that takes user input, and then a `while` loop that does nothing. Apparently you only want a `while` loop, so move the `for` loop's body into the `while`'s loop body.

Comment: Can a user only input 3 numbers?

Comment: Hi, User can input more than 3 numbers.

Comment: Target sum is 6, that's all

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete example.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        try
           {
            int i = 0;
            int number;
            int input=0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter target number ");

            number =   int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (input != number && input < number)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Enter number  {i+1}");
                input += int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                i++;


            }
            Console.WriteLine($"It took {i} number to make the sum {number}");


          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {



          }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what number the user will enter? No, you do not know. So you do not know how many numbers will it take to reach the sum as well.

Pick the right tool for the job.

**For Loop**

A "For" Loop is used to repeat a specific block of code a **known** number of times.

**While Loop**

A "While" Loop is used to repeat a specific block of code an **unknown** number of times,

Given the above 2 options, your pick should be a `while` loop since you do NOT know how many times you will need to ask the user to enter a number to reach the sum. It may be 1 or many, many times.

In C#, there is also the `do while` loop, which is to be used if you know you must *do* something at least once and possibly more, Therefore, for your case the best option would be to use `do while`.

You may read more on [while loop](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/while_loops.html), [for loop](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/for_loops.html), and [do while](https://www.dotnetperls.com/do).

Answer (score -1):

Your code is perfectly operational. I hope this helps:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Target Value: 6");

int total = 0;
int target = 6;
int i = 1;

while (i <= 4)
{
    Console.Write("Enter #{0}:\t", i);
    total += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    i++;
}

while (total == target);
Console.WriteLine("It took {0} inputs to take the sum to\t{1}",i, total);

Console.ReadLine();
```